# lambda calling another lambda and hitting concurrency threshold of 1000

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, serverless-architecture

Scenario- There is a master lambda who is splitting work and giving it off to multiple other lambdas (workers). The first lambda iterates and invokes the other lambdas asynchronously

If the number of lambdas which are getting spawned are more than 1000, will it fail?

Should there be an SNS between the two lambdas... so that the SNS will retry?

Or a more complicated approach of putting the messages into a queue and then sending notification of 'X' number of worker lambdas to start polling the queue?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be some kind of decoupling between the producer and consumers. The most obvious way is to have the producer create 1000 messages on an SNS topic and let AWS handle how many consumers are needed (perhaps it can reuse consumer lambdas). Other ways include triggering from records inserted into DynamoDB.

If you want the listeners to pull messages from an SQS queue you'll need to trigger them yourself, which you can do with CloudWatch (maximum 1 trigger per minute)

Answer (score 0):

**If the number of lambdas which are getting spawned are more than 1000 Qn: Will it fail?**

Yes it will Fail. But you can **increase the default limits(1000) to n numbers based on region by requesting AWS Customer Support.**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html

I am not sure about your exact requirements. Based on your requirements you need to **make sure spawning 1000 lambdas is required in your design**.

My suggestions are below

Suggestion 1:-

**AWS Step Functions**

By AWS Step Functions you can invoke your child lambda from master using state machine language. Based on how your master lambda invoked.(ex: Cloudwatch rules, Triggers). For more information goto:-

https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

https://states-language.net/spec.html

Suggestion 2:-

**AWS ECS Container**

From Master Lambda Send Messages to SQS. Launch your child program as ECS Container Service. In Program, you can consume your SQS Messages and Solve your business logic.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html